# In-place integer multiplication

Tags: c, performance, algorithm

I'm writing a program (in C) in which I try to calculate powers of big numbers in an as short of a period as possible. The numbers I represent as vectors of digits, so all operations have to be written by hand.

The program would be much faster without all the allocations and deallocations of intermediary results. Is there any algorithm for doing integer multiplication, *in-place*? For example, the function

```
void BigInt_Times(BigInt *a, const BigInt *b);
```

would place the result of the multiplication of `a` and `b` inside of `a`, *without using an intermediary value*.

Comment: So what's the question? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @Macmade: Is there any algorithm for doing integer multiplication, in-place?

Comment: @Macmade The question is this: "Is there any algorithm for doing integer multiplication, in-place?"; so far, I've written a function that does integer multiplication, but not in-place; and a function for calculating powers (with `log(f)` complexity, where `f` is the complexity of the multiplication function).

Comment: Is there a reason you're writing this instead of using one of the many existing, high-performance, tested, documented, working now bignum libraries already written for C?

Comment: @DourHighArch Learning project.

Comment: This is the kind of question that's fairly easy to answer, ***but*** I would need a white-board to do so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, `muln()` is **2n** (really, n) **by n = 2n** in-place multiplication for unsigned integers. You can adjust it to operate with 32-bit or 64-bit "digits" instead of 8-bit. The modulo operator is left in for clarity.

`muln2()` is **n by n = n** in-place multiplication (as hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8408318/968261)), also operating on 8-bit "digits".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

typedef unsigned char uint8;
typedef unsigned short uint16;
#if UINT_MAX >= 0xFFFFFFFF
typedef unsigned uint32;
#else
typedef unsigned long uint32;
#endif
typedef unsigned uint;

void muln(uint8* dst/* n bytes + n extra bytes for product */,
          const uint8* src/* n bytes */,
          uint n)
{
  uint c1, c2;

  memset(dst + n, 0, n);

  for (c1 = 0; c1 < n; c1++)
  {
    uint8 carry = 0;

    for (c2 = 0; c2 < n; c2++)
    {
      uint16 p = dst[c1] * src[c2] + carry + dst[(c1 + n + c2) % (2 * n)];
      dst[(c1 + n + c2) % (2 * n)] = (uint8)(p & 0xFF);
      carry = (uint8)(p >> 8);
    }

    dst[c1] = carry;
  }

  for (c1 = 0; c1 < n; c1++)
  {
    uint8 t = dst[c1];
    dst[c1] = dst[n + c1];
    dst[n + c1] = t;
  }
}

void muln2(uint8* dst/* n bytes */,
           const uint8* src/* n bytes */,
           uint n)
{
  uint c1, c2;

  if (n >= 0xFFFF) abort();

  for (c1 = n - 1; c1 != ~0u; c1--)
  {
    uint16 s = 0;
    uint32 p = 0; // p must be able to store ceil(log2(n))+2*8 bits

    for (c2 = c1; c2 != ~0u; c2--)
    {
      p += dst[c2] * src[c1 - c2];
    }

    dst[c1] = (uint8)(p & 0xFF);

    for (c2 = c1 + 1; c2 < n; c2++)
    {
      p >>= 8;
      s += dst[c2] + (uint8)(p & 0xFF);
      dst[c2] = (uint8)(s & 0xFF);
      s >>= 8;
    }
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  uint8 a[4] = { 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00 };
  uint8 b[2] = { 0xFF, 0xFF };

  printf("0x%02X%02X * 0x%02X%02X = ", a[1], a[0], b[1], b[0]);
  muln(a, b, 2);
  printf("0x%02X%02X%02X%02X\n", a[3], a[2], a[1], a[0]);

  a[0] = -2; a[1] = -1;
  b[0] = -3; b[1] = -1;
  printf("0x%02X%02X * 0x%02X%02X = ", a[1], a[0], b[1], b[0]);
  muln2(a, b, 2);
  printf("0x%02X%02X\n", a[1], a[0]);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0xFFFF * 0xFFFF = 0xFFFE0001
0xFFFE * 0xFFFD = 0x0006
```

I think this is the best we can do in-place. One thing I don't like about `muln2()` is that it has to accumulate bigger intermediate products and then propagate a bigger carry.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the standard algorithm consists of multiplying every digit (word) of 'a' with every digit of 'b' and summing them into the appropriate places in the result.  The i'th digit of a thus goes into every digit from i to i+n of the result.  So in order to do this 'in place' you need to calculate the output digits down from most significant to least.  This is a little bit trickier than doing it from least to most, but not much...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you really need an algorithm.  Rather, you need better use of the language's features.

Why not just create that function you indicated in your answer?  Use it and enjoy!  (The function would likely end up returning a reference to *a* as its result.)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, big-int representations vary in length depending on the value represented; in general, the result is going to be longer than either operand.  In particular, for multiplication, the size of the resulting representation is roughly the sum of the sizes of the arguments.

If you are certain that memory management is truly the bottleneck for your particular platform, you might consider implementing a multiply function which updates a third value.  In terms of your C-style function prototype above:

```
void BigInt_Times_Update(const BigInt* a, const BigInt* b, BigInt* target);
```

That way, you can handle memory management in the same way C++ std::vector<> containers do: your update target only needs to reallocate its heap data when the existing size is too small.

Comment: I already have something like the function you suggested (except it returns the value). Also, I have a constraint to only use C features.

Comment: I didn't mean to *use* std::vector<> .  I meant that, if you have functions that update your BigInt (instead of returning a new one), you can keep the heap-allocated memory around instead of reallocating it, as long as you don't need more space.  This is how std::vector<> does its dynamic allocation; I was suggesting you follow its example...

Comment: I have edited my answer; please take a look and see if it is any clearer.