# How to avoid cloning a big integer in rust

Tags: reference, rust, pass-by-reference, biginteger, borrow-checker

I used the [num::BigUInt](https://crates.io/crates/num-bigint) type to avoid integer overflows when calculating the factorial of a number.

However, I had to resort to using `.clone()` to pass rustc's borrow checker.

How can I refactor the factorial function to avoid cloning what could be large numbers many times?

```
use num::{BigUint, FromPrimitive, One};

fn main() {
    for n in -2..33 {
        let bign: Option<BigUint> = FromPrimitive::from_isize(n);
        match bign {
            Some(n) => println!("{}! = {}", n, factorial(n.clone())),
            None => println!("Number must be non-negative: {}", n),
        }
    }
}

fn factorial(number: BigUint) -> BigUint {
    if number < FromPrimitive::from_usize(2).unwrap() {
        number
    } else {
        number.clone() * factorial(number - BigUint::one())
    }
}
```

I tried to use a reference to BigUInt in the function definition but got some errors saying that BigUInt did not support references.

Comment: `BigUint` should support references just fine. You can definitely get it working with enough references (and just one `.clone()`, in the small case) – but that still involves a lot of inefficient intermediate `BigUint` values. Multiplying in place is the right way to do it, like in mcarton’s answer. (You can convert that to tail recursion if you still want some recursion.)

Comment: @Ry I don't think multiplying in place is more efficient. In fact, `x *= y` is [essentially implemented as `x = x * y`](https://github.com/rust-num/num-bigint/blob/3e3487648685dbf4d447fe60ebb1bd4e706038eb/src/biguint.rs#L836-L841), so you get the temporary allocation anyway. (And there is no way to avoid that, since the implementation of the big integer multiplication needs access to the operands while calculating the product.)

Comment: `factorial(0)` is `1` not `0`

Comment: @SvenMarnach: I think it’s avoidable when you also own `y`… but I might be misthinking it.

Comment: @Ry While computing the product, you need to have memory for both the operands and the result. You can't just override one of the operands with the result since the operands are both needed to complete the computation. Many integer multiplication algorithms will need temporary storage on top of this. That's not specific to Rust in any way.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408139/in-place-integer-multiplication is what I was getting at, not that it’s a good idea for a general-purpose bigint library or anything :)

Comment: @SvenMarnach If one of the two numbers is small, as it is here, it's easy to do the multiplication in place without allocating additional memory. In fact that's what `ibig::UBig` will do, regardless of whether you write it as `x *= y` or `x = x * y`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `clone` is easy to remove. You are trying to use `n` twice in the same expression, so don't use just one expression:

```rust
print!("{}! = ", n);
println!("{}", factorial(n));
```

is equivalent to `println!("{}! = {}", n, factorial(n.clone()))` but does not try to move `n` and use a reference to it at the same time.

The second `clone` can be removed by changing `factorial` not to be recursive:

```rust
fn factorial(mut number: BigUint) -> BigUint {
    let mut result = BigUint::one();
    let one = BigUint::one();

    while number > one {
        result *= &number;
        number -= &one;
    }

    result
}
```

This might seem unidiomatic however. There is a [`range`](https://docs.rs/num/0.2.0/num/fn.range.html) function, that you could use with `for`, however, it uses `clone` internally, defeating the point.

Comment: Note that `BigUint::one()` allocates in each call, so this code performs two unnecessary allocations in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think take a `BigUint` as parameter make sense for a factorial. `u32` should be enough:

```rust
use num::{BigUint, One};

fn main() {
    for n in 0..42 {
        println!("{}! = {}", n, factorial(n));
    }
}

fn factorial_aux(accu: BigUint, i: u32) -> BigUint {
    if i > 1 {
        factorial_aux(accu * i, i - 1)
    }
    else {
        accu
    }
}

fn factorial(n: u32) -> BigUint {
    factorial_aux(BigUint::one(), n)
}
```

Or if you really want to keep `BigUint`:

```rust
use num::{BigUint, FromPrimitive, One, Zero};

fn main() {
    for i in (0..42).flat_map(|i| FromPrimitive::from_i32(i)) {
        print!("{}! = ", i);
        println!("{}", factorial(i));
    }
}

fn factorial_aux(accu: BigUint, i: BigUint) -> BigUint {
    if !i.is_one() {
        factorial_aux(accu * &i, i - 1u32)
    } else {
        accu
    }
}

fn factorial(n: BigUint) -> BigUint {
    if !n.is_zero() {
        factorial_aux(BigUint::one(), n)
    } else {
        BigUint::one()
    }
}
```

Both version doesn't do any clone.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [ibig::UBig](https://crates.io/crates/ibig) instead of BigUint, those clones will be free, because ibig is optimized not to allocate memory from the heap for numbers this small.

Answer (score 0):

The task was to avoid the `.clone`, and with the smallest possible change to the OP-solution, this looks like this:

```
fn factorial(number: BigUint) -> BigUint {
    if number <= BigUint::one() {
        BigUint::one()  // 0! == 1
    } else {
        (&number) * factorial(&number - BigUint::one())
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=569bf91c52cb09a47a30c9c02f1a32cc)